# Generate Expressjs API as methods for client side for isomorphic web

Tags: node.js, express, asp.net-web-api

Is there a generator for http services exposed by expressjs that wraps the calls to http get post and offer method wrappers client side for the browser in isomorphic apps ? Kind of what Typelite http://type.litesolutions.net/ offer for C# devs webapi but for nodejs expressjs ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that loopback which is based on express have these generators, for anyone interested in this